# iOS Handling Multiple Asynchronous Requests: Send a Signal When All Requests Are Finished

Tags: iphone, ios, http, asynchronous, asihttprequest

So I am browsing over Stack Overflow for ways to handle asynchronous requests effectively. Right now I am using ASIHTTPRequest and my application consumes a REST API, in which a request to a single resource prompts me to request 5 or more additional resources (linked resources).

Right now I am doing all asynchronous request inside one huge method, there may be around 6 asynchronous request each with their setCompletionBlock and setFailBlock. If you have used ASIHTTPRequest, you must have an idea of how much repetitive code that will take.

Anyway, I seem to have found a solution to determine if all requests are finished with this answer:
[Multiple asynchronous URL requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611191/multiple-asynchronous-url-requests/5611222#5611222)

however, I don't know how to apply that answer in code ,as I have not used push notifications before and I have always used "self" as delegats and never other classes.

Any ideas how I can apply the answer to code or better yet, do you know of any other methods?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all the requests into an ASINetworkQueue: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#about_ASINetworkQueues.

ASINetworkQueue has a callback called "queueDidFinishSelector".

Comment: This library throws lots of ARC errors which you try to import it in iOS application 6 and above.

Answer (score 3):

Use a GCD group with dispatch_group_wait.

Example:

```
__block NSMutableArray *imageURLList = [NSMutableArray array];

dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

for (Helper *siteURL in list) {
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:siteURL]];
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error;
        NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        if (urlData.length)
            [imageURLList urlData];
    });
}

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Note that the block is executed async so it is alright to use `sendSynchronousRequest:`.

Comment: Actually, you still shouldn't do it. In addition to no parsing on the fly, you cannot handle proxy or other authentication, and the operation cannot be cancelled.

Comment: This code is great for executing dozens of GET requests. The only modifications I made in my code was the removal of the synchronous `dispatch_group_wait()` function, since it's a method that freezes the main thread. This caused problems for me since I was executing 150+ asynchronous, and the requests that took a long time kept the app in a frozen state. The app runs fine (and the requests all complete) without having to wait. For RESTful calls, requests will timeout eventually, so the last line of code really isn't necessary, IMHO. I'm definitely open to discussion on it though.